# Is there a way to run a class of a decompiled apk in python without actually running the application?

Tags: python, java, java-native-interface, apk, native

I have decompiled an apk using jadx-gui and I notice the app uses a native library inside one of the classes. I just want to see how I can run a method in a class without actually running the apk file in an android emulator. I want to write a script in python that runs that class method and returns me with the result.

Class code of the decompiled apk is below:

```
package com.test.bap;

import java.util.Base64;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;

/* loaded from: classes.dex */
public final class JniBridge {
    static {
        if ("btap".length() > 0) {
            System.loadLibrary("btap");
        }
    }

    private final native byte[] performAction(int i, String str);

    public final String a(String... params) {
        String encodeToString = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(performAction(12345, params[0]));
        return encodeToString;
    }
}
```

I have tried to load the library using the following code but it doesn't work.

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin\1\recompile\resources\lib\armeabi-v7a\libbtap.so")
print(type(libc))
```

but get the error:

```
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have been able to hook to the application in an android emulator and see the input arguments and return value using objection hooking watch method. However, I want to code this in Python and I don't want to run the app in an android emulator. I just want to use replicate that class code in Python.
Can someone please guide me with how I can achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Native android libraries are not windows DLLs. I don't believe you can load a native android library on windows the way you are trying. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides — if you're trying to port this to python, is it possible for you to remove the calls to the native library and replace them with a comparable python library?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply load a library compiled for a completely different processor and expect it to work. You will need to set up an armeabi-v7a environment using, say, QEMU so you have a host process that can load the DLL.

But that is not all! The very first thing this `performAction` function will do is call into the JVM function pointer table (also called `JNIEnv*`) to retrieve information the supplied String object. Very probably that is not the *only* JVM call it will make. So you will also need to load this DLL from a JVM that has a sufficiently similar environment that the native code does not encounter a missing class or method.

In summary, you need **far** more tooling than just Python.

Comment: I have a x86 and x64 environment libbtap.so which should be compatible with my laptop. Can you please guide me on what I need to do?

Comment: Still the same, except you can use your native environment and JVM now.

Comment: Anyway, the quickest way forward is to add a `main` function to that jnibridge class which creates an instance of the class and calls `performAction` with some parameters. You can then compile the Java file and run it as usual. I would not be surprised if it bombs out because it is missing several other classes, so you will need to make those available as well.